List of words to present equations in an article
I have 13 equations (LaTeX: \eqref) (constraints more precisely) to present in an article's paragraph and, as a non-native, I would welcome any other suggestions to present these constraints in order to avoid repeating oneself too much in the context of Academia.
Here is what I have currently found and used:

Constraints \eqref... state that...
Constraints \eqref enforce...
Constraints \eqref are...
Constraints \eqref set...
Constraints \eqref ensure...
Constraints \eqref allow...
Thanks to constraints \eqref...
With \eqref,...


My suggestion is: don't worry about repeating yourself in cases like this. This piece of grade school writing advice might not work well in a scientific paper. When certain words have a precise mathematical meaning that you want to convey, you should not go out of your way to avoid using them.
As a fellow romance-language mother-tongue speaker, I also have difficulties in un-learning certain habits, flourishes, and involved sentences that are seen as elegant in my native language. But English, especially scientific English, is different: use short, simple, direct sentences; use a boring word order; repetition is fine when a certain word or sentence structure is the best one.

+1 Parallel sentence structure is actually recommended by guides such as The Elements of Style.

Those are all reasonable. But not really synonyms so it depends what you're trying to say.
You could use 'satisfied' or 'emerge'. For example: Constraints \eqref are automatically satisfied because of ..., the constraints in \eqref emerge due to ... etc
You don't necessarily need to write 'constraints' every time. Eg. According to \eqref ..., Using \eqref ..., Substituting \eqref into \eqref ..., etc
You could use 'Equation' instead of 'Constraint': Equation \eqref shows that ..., Equation \eqref requires .... etc. Or even '\eqref captures' ... although I personally try to avoid starting a sentence with a number.
